# 17.10 apt-get upgrade hangs on removing kernel

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` the process hangs on:

```
ak@XPS15:~$ sudo apt-get update
OK:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
OK:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease                                                        
OK:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                  
OK:4 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                       
OK:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                                                               
OK:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease                                                        
OK:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease                                                      
OK:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu artful InRelease                                       
OK:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease                                          
OK:10 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-proposed InRelease                                                    
OK:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu artful InRelease                                        
OK:12 http://archive.canonical.com artful InRelease                          
OK:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu zesty InRelease
OK:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rael-gc/rvm/ubuntu zesty InRelease
OK:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu zesty InRelease
OK:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/corebird/ubuntu artful InRelease
OK:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu zesty InRelease        
OK:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu artful InRelease    
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig                                           
ak@XPS15:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-11-generic
Die folgenden Pakete sind zurückgehalten worden:
  fwupdate libfwup1 linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade):
  firefox firefox-locale-de firefox-locale-en
3 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 1 zu entfernen und 5 nicht aktualisiert.
1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 45,6 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 163 MB Plattenplatz freigegeben.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] J
(Lese Datenbank ... 305580 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Entfernen von linux-image-extra-4.13.0-11-generic (4.13.0-11.12) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-11-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-11-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-11-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-11-generic
```

When I run `sudo apt autoremove -f` it looks like this (hangs on the same action):

```
ak@XPS15:~$ sudo apt autoremove -f
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete werden ENTFERNT:
  linux-image-extra-4.13.0-11-generic
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 1 zu entfernen und 8 nicht aktualisiert.
1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Nach dieser Operation werden 163 MB Plattenplatz freigegeben.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] J
(Lese Datenbank ... 305580 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Entfernen von linux-image-extra-4.13.0-11-generic (4.13.0-11.12) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.13.0-11-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-11-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.13.0-11-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-11-generic
```

The script `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal` runs without any errors or output.

The script `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms` runs without any output but the terminal cursor stops blinking after a while and it hangs. But nor error messages.

I also tried `apt-get install -f` with same result. Ubuntu is installed on my Dell XPS 15.

Thanks & Regards, Andreas

Comment: What does `Entfernen von ` mean?

Comment: it means "removing"

Comment: Can you please post the entire command and output

Comment: @Panther, I have updated the post. I'm sorry it contains german words, if I need to translate anything please let me know.

Comment: May I ask why this question was downvoted?

Comment: I dont know why it was downvoted. Can you try `sudo apt autoremove -f` if that fails, can you try manually running those 2 scripts and post any errors `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal` and `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms` . Those scripts may take /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-11-generic as an arguement

Comment: @Panther thanks again, I have updated the question.

Comment: Is this an upgrade ? You have a lot of repositories and they are mixed, ie you are using a mix of zesty and artful. I would not advise you use mixed repositories. Second, is your /boot partition full ? Go through these steps http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/  try to remove the "linux-image-extra-4.13.0-11-generic" package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68644/discussion-between-kernification-and-panther).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Panther I was able to fix this. It looks like the issue was caused by a full boot partition. So apt-get did not work anymore. 
According to https://linux-audit.com/troubleshooting-full-boot-partition-ubuntu/ I was able to remove old unused kernels with this command:

```
dpkg --purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,image-extra,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")
```

The command `uname -r` is now showing only the current active kernel and everything works fine now.

To list all installed kernels you can type:

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute an edge case answer for this issue that just happened to me. On an HP Pavilion Touch 14-N009LA, with a broken internal HD, running Debian Buster from an external USB drive, upgrading the kernel resulted in an approximately 5 minutes long hang.

The issue was because grub-install, with Debian's default configuration, probes for physically installed OSes on all connected hard drives, including the laptop's broken internal HD, causing grub-install to hang for about 5 minutes as grub-install struggled to find Windows 8.1 on the hard drive.